# Parsing GraphQL failure() result in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graphql

I am relatively new to Swift and am having trouble parsing the result of a GraphQL API call.

I see the result within the 'failure()' declaration is of the type NSError and I'm basically trying to access it if it is a 'failure' and then access the NSError keys. The result is:

```
failure(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x282232700 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x280e54b40 [0x1faa4fcf0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x1002005036d7fb9f0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://staging.mysite.com/api/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://staging.mysite.com/api/v2/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.})
```

I get the below information by using:

```
print("\(result)")
```

Result is an object of type `Result<GraphQLResult<Data>, Error>`. There are methods to get errors but this result apparently isn't thrown as a GraphQL Error. The error catch I'm using is:

```
if let firstError = try? result.get().errors?.first {
    completion([], [], firstError)
    return
}
```

It passes this check so it is just interpreting it as a normal data result. My question is how do I parse this information?

My thinking is that I need to check if it is a failure, then unwrap it from the 'failure' type and then can treat the enclosed info as an NSError object. I can't use 'contains' since it's not a String. There is a `get()` method on `result` that allows you to `result.get().data` or `result.get().error` but neither return anything in this case.

Any help on how I can parse this information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result is a generic swift enumeration, which has two states: success or failure.

To get the error from the failure one must use a switch statement, for eg:

```
switch result {
   case .failure(let error):
     //Handle error here
    default:
       break
 }
```

More on the Result enumeration here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result.

Comment: how we can cast this error to GraphQLError ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
  Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: YourQuery(types:dataSource)) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let graphQLResult):
            print("Success! Result: \(String(describing: graphQLResult.data))")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failure! Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```